# python dependency error [Jinja2 -> Markupsafe] while installing a custom package [MYPACKAGE]

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, package, jinja2

I am trying to install a package  which has Jinja2==2.10 as dependency package.
And Jinja in turn has a dependency on Markupsafe but when it is installing markupsafe it is giving a conflicting error.
Why is the version installed of Markupsafe is "0.0.0" ?

I tried the following to no avail:

1. manually installing markupsafe version 1.1
2. manually install Jinja2==2.10

   ```
      Downloading/unpacking MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10->MYPACKAGE)
      Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.0a1.tar.gz
      Running setup.py egg_info for package MarkupSafe

        no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
        warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      Source in ./build/MarkupSafe has the version 0.0.0, which does not match the requirement MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10->nsscli==1.4.4)
    Source in ./build/MarkupSafe has version 0.0.0 that conflicts with MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10->MYPACKAGE)
    Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
    dpkg: error processing MYPACKAGE (--install):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     MYPACKAGE
   ```